# How do you find clusters based on association rules in data mining/data science?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-science, data-mining

Suppose you have a database

```
Transcation-ID    Item_list
1                 [bread, butter, milk, diaper]
2                 [bread, butter]
3                 [coke, diaper]
4                 [Chips, beer, bread]
```

In this case after finding the association rules, how do we find the similar items based on the association rules (that is cluster similar ***items***)?

Hence, how do we cluster the items such as "Bread", "Butter", "Milk" on the same isle and "chips", "beer","coke" together on an another isle? How do we find the cluster items using the association rules? How do we observe or read the association rules?

Answer (score 0):

How is this ms from a cluster?

```
1 [bread, butter, milk, diaper]
```

Every itemset is a cluster, of similar items.

Answer (score -1):

1. Based on the similarity scores we can find the similar transactions on setting threshold similarity score.

But finding the similar transaction will take more space and time.